# TextBox keydown event at server side in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, textbox, datalist, onkeydown, custompaging

i have a textbox on a page, now whenever any age number is entered in that page, that page should be loaded in my datalist, i have created rest of the thing, but i am not getting how to trigger the textbox onkeydown event from asp.net, i know working with that from javascript, but the problem is i have below things done in that function:

it applies the currentpage value to the static variable from textbox

it binds the datalist

it enable disable the next previous buttons accordingly

and i dont think this i can do from javascript, anyone have any resolution, how this could be achieved from server side, onkeydown event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the keydown event in a javascript function then do a AJAX call to the server. If this does not suit you, then you could try manually do postback in javascript.

So in your textbox:

```
mytextBox.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return doDataListBind()");
```

Now in the javascript function:

```
function doDataListBind()
{
      __doPostBack("myTextBox"); // etc, etc
     // some other code here...
}
```

More info can be found here:

- http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2005/11/04/59081.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into or using either:

**AJAX Control Toolkit**, or

**JQuery Autocomplete Plugin**

Alternatively you could try to call _postback() function from a client side event/function for your textbox in javascript